# MongoError: WriteConflicts

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, concurrency, conflict

**Schema definitions**
**Users** collection: (**optimisticConcurrency: true**)

```
{
  _id: [Object Id],
  pingedAt: [Date],
  currentBal: [Int32],
  { ...otherUserAttibutes }
}
```

**Bookings** collection (**no optimisticConcurrenc**y imposed on this collection)

```
{
  _id: [Object Id],
  user: [Ref to User -> the user for whom the booking was made],
  status: [0, 1, 2, 3, ...]
  { ...otherBookingAttributes }
}
```

All api calls to the backend have an authenticate() middleware to cross, which authenticates by querying for the user after validating the token in the auth header. Then retrieves the user object and ends up updating the following attribute

***pingedAt → current Date***

**Scenario causing the issue:**

1. At 12:01:01:**100** ms /cancel-booking/:bookingId - PUT call was initiated and a mongoose session is started.

```
    const session = await mongoose.startSession();
    session.startTransaction();
    const booking = await this.bookingsRepository.getBookingWithSession({ _id: bookingId }, session)
```

2. At 12:01:01:**200** ms user makes /bookings - GET call and at 12:01:01:**250** ms the user’s pingedAt is updated during authentication.

```
    user.pingedAt = new Date();
    await user.save();
```

3. By 12:01:01:**300** ms, the booking that was retrieved with session is changed to CANCELLED

```
    booking.status = 3
    await booking.save({ session })
```

4. In the same cancel booking call, we add money to user’s wallet. Say booking fee is 300/-. At 12:01:01:**350** ms we save user object with updated balance.

```
    booking.user.currentBal = booking.user.currentBal + 300
    await booking.user.save({ session });
```

> **WriteConflict** error is thrown as the same user object has already changed at 12:01:01:**250** ms

Error logs

```
MongoError: WriteConflict
  at MessageStream.messageHandler (/home/ubuntu/api.backend.js/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:268:20)
  at MessageStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
  at MessageStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
  at processIncomingData (/home/ubuntu/api.backend.js/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
  MessageStream._write (/home/ubuntu/api.backend.js/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
  at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)
  writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
  at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
  at TLSSocket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:716:22)
  at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
  at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
  at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
  at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
  at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
  at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
  at TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:120:14)}
```